# How to save flash-animation in .flv format in Adobe Flash CS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

Actually I can save it in swf and in avi formats. Is there any correct way to save animation in flv format without using 3rd-party products (like different swf2flv converters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export out your animation as .mov then in the Flash Video Exporter (*should have come installed with Flash*) open that select that .mov file then export out to .flv :) no 3rd party apps needed.

Comment: As of 2016, the product is called **[Adobe Media Encoder for Windows](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=160&platform=Windows)**.